# How to player audio in extjs

Tags: extjs, audio-player

I have a audio-player here. But i don't know how to make a controller for it

```
{
      '&lttpl&gt',
      '&ltaudio style="width: 100%; controls id="audio" src="{host}" autoplay&#47&gt &ltaudio&#47&gt',
      '&lt&#47tpl&gt'
    }
```

Comment: this is a html pure tag not really related to extjs

Answer (score 0):

```
    {
 xtype: 'audio',
 src: 'src Url here',
 autoResume: true,
 autoPause: true,
 enableControls: true
}
```

Ext.Audio and Ext.Video also support the following methods:
Method  Description
- isPlaying()   Returns the current play status as a boolean.
- pause()   Pauses playback.
- play()    Continues playback.
- stop()    Stops playback and returns to the beginning of the loop.
- toggle()  Toggles the playback state.

[Audio Class Extjs2.0](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.1.1/#!/api/Ext.Audio)

Comment: which version of Extjs are you using ??